# Php string not saving into arrary

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am reading a text file and then parse it into a web page. The text file has 3 entries. I want the last entry to show up first, so I am trying to save the text into an array first, and then read it back from the last entry. Seems to me, my $text array is not able to save the string from fgets. I can't figure out what the problem is to the array, and is there a better way to do this?

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$test = fopen("test.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");

while (! feof($test)){

$line=fgets($test);
parse_str($line);
$c=$entry;
$text=array("zero--");

if (strncasecmp( $line, "entry", 5)){

$text[$c] .= $line;
echo "c:". $c. $line. "<br>";
}

}

global $text;
echo "t:". $text[0];
echo "t:". $text[1];

?>
```

Here is the result:

```
c:1 first entry
c:1 It's sunny today
c:1
c:2 Second entry
c:2 It's sunny today too
c:2 Hi, how are you?
c:2
c:3 last entry
c:3 bye
c:3
t:zero--t:
```

Here is my test file.

```
entry=1
first entry
It's sunny today

entry=2
Second entry
It's sunny today too
Hi, how are you?

entry=3 
last entry
bye
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to show the last entry first is to create an array and for example use the ending digit from `entry_1` as the array key. As an array can not have duplicate keys, this should then always be unique.

While reading the lines of the file, you could create an empty array for each key and fill the array. At the end, you could use [`krsort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.krsort.php) sort the array by key in reverse order.

```
$test = fopen("test.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
$results = [];
while (!feof($test)) {
    $line = fgets($test);
    if (strncasecmp($line, "entry=", 6) === 0) { //Compare the first 6 characters
        $index = intval(substr($line, 6), 10); //$index would be 1, 2 or 3
        $results[$index] = []; // Create empty array placeholder to be filled
    }
    $results[$index][] = $line; // Add the line to the current placeholder
}
krsort($results);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        echo $item . "<br>";
    }
}
```

If you want to flatten the array of arrays to 1 array and then use 1 foreach, you could use [call_user_func_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) and [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php):

```
$results = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $results);

foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: after more than 5 hours of writing and testing code, I got it. This is the line of the bug: $c=$entry; $c is a string, not a integer. and so this is a quick and simple fix: $c=(integer )$entry;

Answer (score 0):

After more than 5 hours code writing and testing and googling, this is my final code that works.

First, it reads the text file into an array using a tag of "entry=", and then it echos from the last position using a for loop. That is it. I also added an if statement to ignore the empty line.

```
<?php
$new = file("com/test.txt");

foreach ( $new as $a){

parse_str($a);
$c=(integer )$entry;

    if (strncasecmp( $a, "entry", 5) !=0){

    if(!(ctype_space ( $a ))){
    $text[$c] .= $a. "<br>";
    }
    }
    }

for( $i=$c; $i>0; $i--){
echo $text[$i] . "<br>";
}
?>
```